# AppEngine 1.7.6 and Django 1.4.2 release

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-nonrel

AppEngine 1.7.6 has promoted Django 1.4.2 to GA.
I wonder how and if people this are using The reason for my question is that Django-nonrel seems to be stuck on Django 1.3 and there are no signs of an updated realease.

What I would like to use from Djano are controllers, views and especially form validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to use controllers, views and form validations you still can do it.

Django comes built-in in Google App Engine, so you can write your Django application inside. What's the problem? That Django models are relational but datastore is not. You have 2 options there:

- Use [CloudSQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/?hl=es-419), that way you will be able to use normal Django models with a MySQL-like database.
- Use everything from Django but the models. Just don't use Django ORM, and use the GAE SDK instead. Or even [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/). You will loose some things like `ModelForms`, but it can make the work.

Comment: Using NDB is fine enough I think.

Comment: Can you comment how main.py should look. I'm looking for an example/best practice but I can't seem to find this on GAE site.

Answer (score 0):

The django library built into GAE is straight up normal django that has an SQL ORM.  So you can use this with Cloud SQL but not the HRD.

django-nonrel is up to 1.4.5 according to the messages on the newsgroup.  The documentation, unfortunately, is sorely behind.